# How do I show multiple, manually opened fancybox galleries?

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I am trying to display several multiple, manually called image galleries using fancybox.  I can get one gallery working, but the second will not open.  Here is the code :

JAVASCRIPT

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.fancybox').fancybox();

            /* MANUAL OPEN */
            $("#fancybox-manual-c").click(function(){
            $.fancybox.open([
                {
                    href : 'image1.jpg',
                    rel : 'set01',
                    title : 'My title'
                }, {
                    href : 'image2.jpg',
                    rel : 'set01',
                    title : '2nd title'
                }, {
                    href : 'image3.jpg',
                    rel : 'set02',
                    title : '3rd title'
                }, {
                    href : 'image4.jpg',
                    rel : 'set02',
                    title : '4th title'
                }
            ]);
        });
        /* END OF MANUAL OPEN */
        });
```

HTML

```
               <div>
                    <a id="fancybox-manual-c" rel="set01" href="javascript:;"><img src="thumbnail01.jpg"></a>
               </div><!-- END OF PICTURE THUMBS -->
               <div><hr /></div>
               <div>
                    <a id="fancybox-manual-c" rel="set02" href="javascript:;"><img src="thumbnail02.jpg"></a>
               </div><!-- END OF PICTURE THUMBS -->
```

I eventually want to somehow call the images so that I'm not having to add lines of code to the file every time I want to upload a picture, but so far I'm struggling to even get two instances working correctly.

Note that I am using fancybox with other links on the page that are working as is, and on the same page I am also calling YouTube videos with no issues, and I have also tried some of the more popular questions with answers on here with no success.

Also, I'm pretty sure I made a mistake copying over sections of that JS code - so any errors with regards to the closing brackets at the end are typos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to change the id values. Group them with an outer div or with the same class name.

[How do I open fancybox via manual call for a gallery in the html not via the jquery options?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10835849/how-do-i-open-fancybox-via-manual-call-for-a-gallery-in-the-html-not-via-the-jqu)

The link might help you.

Comment: Yes I had tried this method, but at first I was seeing all of the pictures displayed on the page.  I figure I can hide the pictures I don't want to see, so that's fine, but I'm not sure I want potentially hundreds of 'a' tags in my HTML that I have to update manually every time I want to upload a new picture.  I think I may have to figure out some php to sort that out.

Comment: This is the correct answer, even though now I am having trouble with the php side (but that's another question)