# Using flexslider to display multiple fancybox galleries

Tags: fancybox, gallery, flexslider

I have a few fancybox galleries in thumbnail format and I would like to use flexslider to shift between them.

I'm trying to accomplish something like this: http://www.herschelsupply.com/lookbook/

Is this possible, and if so, what do I need to do?

I've looked around quite a bit and I know it's possible to run multiple galleries on the same page, but I haven't seen any comments on a setup like the one above.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: does this help ? http://stackoverflow.com/a/9487189/1055987

Comment: Thanks, but I was actually able to get it to work using jquery. https://gist.github.com/563040