# Multiple 'rel' in Fancybox

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I have installed Fancybox and I want to launch different sets of images from different thumbnails. The default makes all images cycle through from all thumbnails. I have found out through trial and error that I can assign a new 'rel' to each set in the html and reflect that in separate js. I was wondering if I can add all the data to one js. Here is the js:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("[rel='set1']").fancybox({
            helpers : {
                thumbs : false
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

The 'set1' is the bit I changed for the first set of images. In the html there is a 'rel that also has 'set1'.

I have 12 sets of images and I'd rather not have 12 of those scripts in my page. Can I add 'set2', 'set3' etc. to the one js script? I've tired many ways but none work for me.

I hope I've made myself clear, I'm pretty new at js.

Kirk

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create separate Fancybox galleries on the same page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9486034/how-to-create-separate-fancybox-galleries-on-the-same-page)

Answer (score 0):

I have fancybox 2.1.5 and instead of using "rel" it now checks the "data-fancybox-group" attribute. It took me stepping through their actual code to find this.

You can override the name of the attribute to be used with the (currently undocumented) groupAttr option. For example, to change it back to rel you'd have `{groupAttr: "rel"}`

https://github.com/fancyapps/fancyBox/issues/288