# How can I easily disable fancybox slideshow?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I, am newbie in jquery plugins.

I've included jquery fancybox plugin on my site and it works perfect, but I want it to only popup my images not slide them.

Pics are on the different parts of the page so they are not logically connected with each other.

I am using this code :

```
$('.fancybox').fancybox();
```

and the images have `class "fancybox"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just remove the `rel` attribute from your links with `class="fancybox"` like

```
<a class="fancybox" href="01.jpg">image 01</a>
<a class="fancybox" href="02.jpg">image 02</a>
```

then use can use this code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox();
});
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/fsxjpczm/1/)**

Comment: thnx, that helped me, btw u can create your own sub galleries using this "rel" attribute

Comment: yes, just bear in mind that members of the same gallery should share the same `rel` and `class` attributes, for instance gallery 1 all links should have `<a class="fancybox" rel="gallery1" href...`, then gallery 2 `<a class="fancybox" rel="gallery2" href...` and so on and so forth. All galleries can use the same script `$(".fancybox").fancybox()`. Check http://stackoverflow.com/a/9487189/1055987 for reference.